# "Хорошо быть в такую ночь на пустой дороге" - тип сказуемого?

Tags: сказуемые, наречия

Из [упражнений](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/uprr1_18) на сайте licey.net:

> **Хорошо быть** в такую ночь на пустой дороге (Паустовский).

Согласно [разделу ответов](http://www.licey.net/russian/upr/answers2_1), это безличное односоставное предложение. Сказуемое - "хорошо быть".

Но какой у него тип? Составное глагольное с основной частью "быть" и со вспомогательной частью - составным именным сказуемым, выражающим модальное значение (наречие "хорошо")?

---

P.S.
Согласно тому же сайту, подлежащее может быть выражено инфинитивом. Полагаю, наше предложение по какой-то причине нельзя так интерпретировать (интересно, по какой). На всякий случай [вот](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_1_5) цитата:

> если подлежащее – инфинитив, существительное женского, мужского рода, существительное во множественном числе, то именная часть сказуемого – наречие:
>
> ***Жить** – это **хорошо**; Жизнь – это хорошо; Дети – это хорошо;*

- "**Быть** в такую ночь на пустой дороге - это **хорошо**". (0:

(Подлежащее - сказуемое. Почему бы и нет? Потому что нет тире и нет местоимения "это"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошо быть в такую ночь на пустой дороге (Паустовский). Это один из спорных вопросов ситаксиса. Мнения разные. Возможна и Ваша интерпретация.

Однако в образовательной среде принято придерживаться мнения Розенталя: При сказуемом, выраженном словами на -О, на первом месте обычно стоит подлежащее: Смотреть на всё это грустно. При обратном порядке слов двусоставное предложение становится односоставным, безличным.

Сравните: Плыть на лодке ночью хорошо.Плыть -подлежащее, хорошо-сказуемое. Хорошо плыть на лодке ночью .Хорошо плыть-сказуемое.Такой практики придерживаются и в школе.

А вообще, принципиальная возможность двусоставных предложений с подлежащим - инфинитивом и сказуемым -прилагательным подтверждается существованием конструкций с формой творительного падежа полных прилагательных: Рассказать об этом не так уж сложно.-Рассказать об этом  не было сложным. - прямая оценка действия, выраженного инфинитивом.

Пробуем проверить нашу конструкцию:Быть в такую ночь на пустой дороге является делом хорошим. - смысл поменялся, это уже не чувства, а оценка действия. У нас же - состояние человека, ему хорошо, следовательно, хорошо - это категория состояния и предложение безличное.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Понятно: Розенталь делает упор на порядок слов в таких предложениях. Мне как раз и хотелось выяснить "официальную" точку зрения. Хотелось бы ещё узнать, правильно ли я описал сказуемое: *"Простое глагольное с основной частью "быть" и со вспомогательной частью - составным именным сказуемым, выражающим модальное значение (наречие "хорошо")*. Может быть, *хорошо* здесь - прилагательное?

Comment: Только не простое, а  СОСТАВНОЕ глагольное.Лексическое значение несёт инфинитив быть,а в роли вспомогательной частикатегория состояния хорошо (каково?, а не как?)

Answer (score 2):

Хорошо быть в такую ночь на пустой дороге.

1)  **Безличное предложение**, в котором предикатив (слово категории состояния) определяет состояние человека. Интересно, что  "хорошо" в этом случае выражает предикативный признак, **но субъект-лицо в качестве носителя признака тоже подразумевается: хорошо мне/ему.**

2) Попутно замечу, что в грамматике Кустовой **сказуемым является только "хорошо", а инфинитив "примыкает" к нему** - скорее всего, на правах дополнения (что хорошо? - быть на дороге). Например: хорошо (что?) иметь много друзей.

3) Но существуют и **двусоставные предложения похожей структуры**, например: Бегать по утрам полезно (бег по утрам полезен). Здесь **предмет и его оценка**.

Но: Полезно (людям для здоровья) бегать по утрам. Мысль уже другая, рассказывается, что полезно. Это безличное предложение.

4) **Быть в такую ночь на пустой дороге  хорошо.** Это двусоставное предложение (предмет и оценка). Субъекта-носителя нет, смысл суждения не очень ясен.

5) Поэтому дело не в трактовке формальной грамматики, **а в смысле**, которое содержит сообщение. И очень важно разобраться, где там предикативный признак (сказуемое), а где носитель этого признака. **Или это подлежащее, выраженное инфинитивом (двусоставное предложение), или это  существительное (местоимение) в косвенном падеже (безличное предложение).**
К примеру, в предложении "В лесу холодно" на носителя состояния (среду) указывает обстоятельство.

Comment: Вера, да, там говорится, что инфинитив может примыкать к словам категории состояния. но о дополнении ничего не говорится. Это действительно СГС. У той же Кустовой говорится, что в составном глагольном сказуемом в качестве связки могут употребляться слова категории состояния.

Comment: Серж, меня в этой истории вот что смущает. Мы говорим, что в безличном предложении предикатив выражает СОСТОЯНИЕ лица. Но состояние определяется одним словом - хорошо, инфинитив просто дополняет  тему (что именно хорошо). А в СГС инфинитив передает ОСНОВНОЕ содержание, а модальные и фазовые вспомогательные глаголы (или модальные слова)  вносят дополнительные значения. Как-то всё наоборот.

Comment: Вера, если честно, я не понял вашу мысль: вы хотите сказать, что в безличном предложении слова категории состояния  вносят дополнительные значения, а в СГС - инфинитив дополняет тему. Да?

Comment: Да нет, Серж, все наоборот. В СГС инфинитив  - это всегда главное содержание, а в безличном предложении  (в нашем случае)  основное содержание  передает  предикатив "хорошо". .Но так бывает не всегда, например: "надо ехать", здесь предикатив "надо" - вспомогательный, а глагол "ехать" - основной.

Comment: Также обратите внимание на вариант "Жаль, что он ушел". Здесь предикатив "жаль" распространяется целым предложением, а  не одним инфинитивом (жаль уходить).

Comment: Ну да, так же , как в нашем предложении: хорошо быть - предикатив. Я бы даже сказал: надо ехать - предикатив.

Comment: У Кустовой только "хорошо" выделено как предикатив черным шрифтом. Поэтому надо выбирать: примыкающий инфинитив - это или дополнение, или инфинитив в СГС. "Хорошо" - это самодостаточное слово, оно может быть сказуемым.  А вот слово "надо"  обязательно связано с действием, оно только вспомогательное.

Comment: Странно, Вера, я не заметил. Там было написано, что инфинитив может примыкать к словам категории состояния. но о дополнении ничего не говорится. И не было выделено черным шрифтом.

Comment: Вы читали это в теме "Безличные предложения"?

Comment: О дополнении там ничего нет, но и про СГС вида "хорошо + инфинитив" ничего нет тоже. В разделе "Безличные предложения"  рассказывается, чем выражается слова категории состояния, в частности есть примеры: НУЖНО ехать, ХОРОШО иметь много друзей. А в разделе, посвященном СГС, таких примеров нет, там названы разные модальные слова, но только не эти. Как будто автор обходит эти темы.

Comment: В разделе  СГС говорится, что в качестве связки могут быть использованы слова категории состояния, правда примеров нет.

Answer (score 1):

### Грамма.ру

Предикаты безличного предложения не полностью повторяют систему сказуемых двусоставного предложения, поэтому использование терминов ПГС, СГС и СИС применительно к безличному предложению не вполне корректно. 
Если Вы все же хотите применить эту терминологию к безличным предикатам, то Ваш пример больше подходит под составное глагольное сказуемое, где слово "хорошо" имеет модально-оценочное значением, а "быть" является инфинитивом полнозначного сказуемого.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, в общем, да. Потому что нет тире и местоимения "это". Если шире — потому что синтаксис у предложений совсем разный.

Answer (score 0):

Традиция. Тут такая штука. Формальная грамматика - я обычно говорю "модель грамматики", чтобы различать собтвенно грамматику и наши представления о ней - так вот, любая модель грамматики неполна. Всегда найдется случай, который можно трактовать по-разному, оставаясь в рамках строгой системы правил грамматического разбора.

Тут мы имеем как раз такой случай. Обе трактовки грамматической структуры предложения не противоречат правилам. "Математикам" с этим бывает трудно смириться, но гуманитарии прекрасно с эти живут, основываясь на подходах авторитетных учебников, которые считают синтаксис разным - и относят предложения к тому или иному типу "по прецеденту" (или потому, что так условный Розенталь сказал).

ЗЫ Я правильно понимаю, что Вши вопросы не требуют конкретного ответа, Вы просто хотите разобраться с ситуацией неоднозначности при грамматическом разборе?

Comment: Боюсь, что я не настолько сведущ в русской грамматике, чтобы углубляться в тонкости.. Хотел просто узнать, как разбирают такие предложения в школе, по "условным Розенталям". (0:

Answer (score 0):

Сказуемое здесь - модальное слово! А прочие глаголы - дополнения. Смысл высказывания в модальности!

В области теории модальности русский язык сильно отстал от английского!

Comment: Т.е. сказуемое "хорошо" и дополнение "быть"? ("Хорошо быть в такую ночь на пустой дороге")

Comment: Интересно, как это язык может "отстать в теории"?